Netbeans specify the target runtime as a build parameter
When I try and compile my project this is the error message I get
The recommended solution is :

When I look in ~.gradle\caches I have multiple versions 8.0-rc-1 and 8.9
I would like to know how to get the project to use version 8.9 instead of 8.0-rc-1 (I have 8.9 installed)
or
how to set up the correct Build>Gradle Execution setting. I have got as far as :

but don't know how to specify the runtime version here.
How do I fix this?
Thanks

For me the solution turned out to changing the version of gradle used.

This had to be changed to gradle version 8.9 as below:

This file was in the project/gradle/wrapper directory.
